Correctly tear down process when using pytest with multiprocessing
I am working on a package that includes a server with the corresponding client.
I was thinking that I could save a lot of effort mocking all the interactions and just write some test cases that test both sides at the same time.
So I wrote a fixture that would yield a multiprocessing.Process instance inside which the server is running.
When the tests are done I tear down the process using process.terminate(). Unfortunately there is another "orphaned" process that I can't seem to get a handle on.
How do I remove the other process or how do I avoid starting it in the first place?
If you know of a way of doing this with a different library than multiprocessing I am totally open to it.
To reproduce the problem I used the code from how-to-make-a-simple-python-rest-server-and-client to create a simple Rest Server/Client Pair.

import asyncio
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp

import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify


def server():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    tasks = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Buy groceries",
            "description": "Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol",
            "done": False,
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Learn Python",
            "description": "Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web",
            "done": False,
        },
    ]

    @app.route("/todo/api/v1.0/tasks", methods=["GET"])
    def get_tasks():
        return jsonify({"tasks": tasks})

    app.run()


class TestMultiprocessingTester:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def server_process(self):
        server_process = mp.Process(target=server)
        server_process.start()
        yield server_process
        server_process.terminate()
        if server_process.is_alive():
            server_process.kill()
        logging.getLogger("Process").warning("shut down server process")

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_client(self, server_process: mp.Process):
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        url = "http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks"
        response = requests.get(url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json()["tasks"][0]["done"] is False




In order to be able to get ride of zombies, here what does doc say:

On Unix when a process finishes but has not been joined it becomes a
zombie. There should never be very many because each time a new
process starts (or active_children() is called) all completed
processes which have not yet been joined will be joined. Also calling
a finished process’s Process.is_alive will join the process. Even so
it is probably good practice to explicitly join all the processes that
you start.

So in order to avoid zombies, you need to call the process join() method once you kill it.
